# Convert roman number to arabic using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to convert roman numerals to arabic using javascript. I wrote a code but it is failing. 
The rules I am trying to follow are :

if Larger number is before smaller number then addition and if smaller number is before larger number then subtraction.

Along with that I have few other rules as well like 'D','L' and 'V' can't be repeated at all and 'M' can be repeated only twice (Not sure how to implement this, can I use regex for it and how?)

Code :

```js
    function romanToArabic(roman){
        if(roman == null)
            return -1;
            var value;
        for(var i=0;i<roman.length;i++){
            current = char_to_int(roman.charAt(i));
            next = char_to_int(roman.charAt(i+1));
            console.log("Current",current);
            console.log("Next",next);
            if(current >= next){
                value = current + next;
                console.log(value);
            }
            else {
                console.log(value);
                value = next - current;
            } 
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    function char_to_int(character) {
        switch(character){
            case 'I': return 1;
            case 'V': return 5;
            case 'X': return 10;
            case 'L': return 50;
            case 'C': return 100;
            case 'D': return 500;
            case 'M': return 1000;
            default: return -1;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(romanToArabic('IIX'));
```

Can somebody help? Would appreciate it!

Added screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"I have few other rules as well like 'I' and 'C' can't be repeated at all"*: ehh, then how do you get 2?

Comment: Every iteration takes into account two characters, but then the index is incremented by only 1

Comment: if index is incremented by 2 it would get stuck into endless loop. I have already tried that! the problem is for second iteration it should go to else part but it is still checking the if part

Comment: @Anju Check my response! It's work fine for me, tested on jsfiddle !

Comment: for my case it is giving me wrong output plus in the validator it reads for the value which starts with M

Comment: Can you giv me an example for a wrong output ? The validator work fine!!

Comment: I tried IIX it failed then I removed validator and now it is giving me output as 10 where as according to the rules which I mentioned I need the output as 8. I am kind of new to javascript. I have added the screenshots of the output in the question

Comment: @Anju In romans numerical **8 = VIII** not **IIX** !!! Use this [converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/roman-numerals-converter.html) for more informations!

Comment: I know that but I have been given different set of rules which I have mentioned in the question if the smaller number is mentioned before larger number then subtraction has to be performed and if its vice versa then addition. and even for IIX i should be getting 12 according to normal rules of roman numericals not 10. 10 is X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code only subtracts the value corresponding to *one* character, while in `IIX` you need to subtract twice (although that kind of representation for the number 8 is quite unconventional -- 8 would normally be represented as `VIII`).

The solution is to keep collecting a separate sum for when the symbol is the same, so that after reading the first two "I", you have two separate sums:

- total: 2
- value of all "I": 2

Then when you encounter the "X" and detect that a subtraction is needed, you first undo the addition already done for the grand total, and then perform the subtraction with the value you collected for the "I":

- total: -2

After this, you start with a reset value for "X":

- total: 10 + -2 = 8
- value for all "X": 10

Here is your code adapted for that to happen:

```js
function romanToArabic(roman){
    if(roman == null)
        return -1;
    var totalValue = 0, 
        value = 0, // Initialise!
        prev = 0;
        
    for(var i=0;i<roman.length;i++){
        var current = char_to_int(roman.charAt(i));
        if (current > prev) {
            // Undo the addition that was done, turn it into subtraction
            totalValue -= 2 * value;
        }
        if (current !== prev) { // Different symbol?
            value = 0; // reset the sum for the new symbol
        }
        value += current; // keep adding same symbols
        totalValue += current;
        prev = current;
    }
    return totalValue;
}

function char_to_int(character) {
    switch(character){
        case 'I': return 1;
        case 'V': return 5;
        case 'X': return 10;
        case 'L': return 50;
        case 'C': return 100;
        case 'D': return 500;
        case 'M': return 1000;
        default: return -1;
    }
}

console.log(romanToArabic('IIX'));
```

As for your additional question to limit the number of consecutive "I" to at most two, "D" at most one, ... you could use a regular expression test at the start of your function:

```
if (/III|XXX|CCC|MMM|VV|LL|DD|[^IVXLCDM]/.test(roman)) 
    return -1;
```

You can just append other invalid sub-sequences separated by `|`. For instance, if you would not want an "I" to appear directly in front of "L", "C", "D" or "M", then extend to:

```
if (/III|XXX|CCC|MMM|VV|LL|DD|[^IVXLCDM]|I[LCDM]/.test(roman)) 
    return -1;
```

Comment: it can be repeated twice but not thrice. and some characters like 'D' ,'L' and 'V' can't be repeated. Can you suggest me what can be done for this?

Comment: Do you mean they cannot be repeated at all, or not repeated when they occur before a bigger roman character. For example, I think 'DDV' should be OK, but maybe not 'DDM'?

Comment: 'DVD' is okay but not 'DDV' and 'IIX' is okay 'IIIX' is not

Comment: And is `III` OK?

Comment: Eh no its like I can be repeated twice only not thrice similarly 'C' ,'X' and 'M' can be repeated twice only

Comment: You can use a regex test at the start of the function, like `if (/III|XXX|CCC|MMM|VV|LL|DD|[^IVXLCDM]/.test(roman)) 
        return -1;`

Answer (score 4):

To those, who might need to translate [**conventional**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) roman numbers as opposed to **irregular subtractive notation** (e.g. 'IIX' instead of 'VIII' for 8), I might suggest my own, slightly shorter method:

```js
const test = ['XIV'/*14*/, 'MXMVI'/*1996*/, 'CII'/*102*/, 'CDI'/*401*/];

const roman2arabic = s => {
  const map = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000};
  return [...s].reduce((r,c,i,s) => map[s[i+1]] > map[c] ? r-map[c] : r+map[c], 0);
};

console.log(test.map(roman2arabic));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Though, it can be modified to follow unconventional logic:

```js
const test = ['IIV'/*3*/,'XXMMII'/*1982*/, 'IIIXV'/*12*/, 'XII'/*conventional 12*/];

const roman2arabic = s => {
  const map = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000};
  return [...s]
    .reduceRight(({sum,order},c,i,s) => 
      Object.keys(map).indexOf(c) < order ? 
      {sum: sum-map[c], order} : 
      {sum: sum+map[c], order: Object.keys(map).indexOf(c)},
    {sum:0,order:Object.keys(map).indexOf(s[s.length-1])})
    .sum;
};

console.log(test.map(roman2arabic));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

const romans = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000
    };

```
// MXMIV
function roman2arabic(nums){
    let sum = 0;
    const numsArr = nums.split('');
    const isSimpleRoman = (num) => num in romans;
    const arabicCompare = (current, prev) => romans[current] < romans[prev];

    const orderNums = (acc, current) => {
        const prev = acc[acc.length - 1] || null;
        const arabCurrent = romans[current];

        if (prev && isSimpleRoman(prev) && arabicCompare(current, prev)) {
            sum -= arabCurrent;
            acc.pop() && acc.push(current + prev);
        } else {
            sum += arabCurrent;
            acc.push(current);
        }
        return acc;
    };

    return numsArr.reduceRight(orderNums, []) && sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const romans = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000
    };

```
function roman2arabicRecursion(nums){
    const numsArr = nums.split('');
    const recursion = (arr, index, sum) => {
        const current =  arr[index];
        const prev = arr[index + 1] || null;

        if(prev && romans[current] < romans[prev]){
            sum -= romans[current];
        } else {
            sum += romans[current];
        }

        if(index === 0) return sum;

        return recursion(arr, index - 1, sum);
    }

    return recursion(numsArr, numsArr.length - 1, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively **||** operator could be used isntead of **??**

```js
const toArabic = (romanNumber) => {
    const map = {
    M: 1000,
    D: 500,
    C: 100,
    L: 50,
    X: 10,
    V: 5,
    I: 1,
    };

    const nums = romanNumber.split('');
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 1) {
      const first = map[nums[i]];
      const second = map[nums[i + 1]] ?? 0;
      if (first < second) {
        result += second - first;
        i += 1;
      } else {
        result += first;
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
  console.log(toArabic('CMXI')); // 911
  console.log(toArabic('MXXIV')); // 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

We are so used to reading from Left to Right, we overlook the Right to Left alternatives.

The whole point of Roman notation is you want to check if **V** becomes *before* **X**

That is much easier when you ***reverse*** the Roman string.

Or in JavaScript, use the hardly ever used `reduceRight` method

(code optimized for better GZIP/Brotli compression)

```js
const romanToArabic = (input) => [...input].reduceRight((
  acc,
  letter,
  idx,
  arr,
  value = {m:1000, d:500, c:100, l:50, x:10, v:5, i:1}[letter.toLowerCase()],
  doubleSubtraction = letter == arr[idx + 1] // ignore IIX notation
) => {
  if (value < acc.high && !doubleSubtraction)
    acc.Arabic -= value;
  else
    acc.Arabic += acc.high = value;
  //console.log(idx, letter, acc, 'value:', value, acc.high, arr[idx + 1]);
  return acc;
}, { high:0, Arabic:0 }).Arabic; // return Arabic value

//TESTS
Object.entries({
    "cxxiv": 124,
    "ix": 9,
    "iix": 10,
    "xL": 40,
    "MMMDXLIX": 3549,
    "MMMMCMXCIX": 4999}
  ).map(([roman,value])=>{
    let converted = romanToArabic(roman);
    console.log(roman, "=", converted);
    console.assert(converted == value, "wrong conversion,", roman, "must be", value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this exercise like this:

```
function arabic(num) {
    let ch;
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        ch = num[i];
        switch (ch) {
            case 'I':
                if (num[i + 1] === 'V' || num[i + 1] === 'X') {
                    continue;
                }
                sum = sum + 1;
                break;
            case 'V':
                if (num[i - 1] === 'I') {
                    sum = sum + 4;
                    break;
                }
                sum = sum + 5;
                break;
            case 'X':
                if (num[i - 1] === 'I') {
                    sum = sum + 9;
                    break;
                }
                if (num[i + 1] === 'C') {
                    continue;
                }
                sum = sum + 10;
                break;
            case 'L':
                sum = sum + 50;
                break;
            case 'C':
                if (num[i + 1] === 'D' || num[i + 1] === 'M') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (num[i - 1] === 'X') {
                    sum = sum + 90;
                    break;
                }
                sum = sum + 100;
                break;
            case 'D':
                if (num[i - 1] === 'C') {
                    sum = sum + 400;
                    break;
                }
                sum = sum + 500;
                break;
            case 'M':
                if (num[i - 1] === 'C') {
                    sum = sum + 900;
                    break;
                }
                sum = sum + 1000;
                break;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```